# UIView Subclassing and OOP

Tags: ios, oop, uiview

I have an app where the model is an array of Menu objects containing information such as title, images, method etc.

I would like to create a scroll view with a list of Menu Views, maybe with picture, title and short description for each menu.

To do this, I would like to subclass UIView and create a MenuView instance for each menu.

My question is how I should communicate the model to the view. As far as I can see I can either:

1. Alloc and init with menu item and layout sub views (means the view sees the model)
2. Alloc and init with title, image and description (means the view doesn't see the model but doesn't seem to offer much advantage)
3. Use delegation so the view asks for information from a data source (seems to be the most segregated but complicated)

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a tableView would be your best choice. Subclass a UITableViewCell and add all your objects to that then you can take advantage of the tableView behavior to make your life easier.

[UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

A quick [iOS UITableView example](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/)

Comment: Would be nice to reference the table view documentation.

Comment: Yeah possibly, it's kind of overkill though, it's just a few views I need. In effect though you're suggesting option 3 I guess as a table view has a datasource and delegate...

Comment: Even if it's just a few views you are re-using code by using cells. You also have the option of using a static table view if doesn't need to be dynamic.

Comment: Okay fair enough. But forget about the list for a second, what happens in the scenario where there is just one subview for example?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If you are saying you may only have one cell and it may have larger sized content you can easily adjust the height of the cell using heightForRowAtIndex so it fills the amount of useable area. TableViews are highly customizable since they are just subclassed UIScrollViews. That's why I recommended a tableView instead of a raw UIScrollView.

Comment: My question is about the philosophy of separating the model from the view, not about uitableviewcell. UITableViewCell is an example where the model is held in a datasource, this means that a table with 1000 rows doesn't have to have the views all loaded at once but can call on the datasource as necessary. My question is whether this is a usual software architecture practice when you are designing any custom UIView or whether it is more usual to just pass the model to the view when you are initialising.

Comment: Your question says "array of Menu objects containing information such as title, images, method etc.". In this case your datasource is simply an array of objects that holds each of the items. Whether you choose to use all objects at once is completely up to the use case. Efficiency is generally the best practice but that doesn't mean you have to follow it. Use what is best for your scenario but based on what you described I gave my best answer for the case you described. You could create a scrollview and fill each view using an array and not reuse cells if you wanted to pre-render everything.